# How to Debug {"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_SYSTEM_CONFIG"}} []

Tags: nginx, magento2.3.3, debug, centos

My Centos - Nginx Configuration,

**etc/nginx/conf.d/magento.conf**

```
server {
listen 8087;
server_name abc;
set $MAGE_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/html/abc;
include /usr/share/nginx/html/abc/nginx.conf.sample;

error_log /usr/share/nginx/html/abc/abc_error.log;
access_log /usr/share/nginx/html/abc/abc_access.log;
```

}

upstream fastcgi_backend2 {
        server  127.0.0.1:9000;
}

And i am getting following response,

> [2020-01-18 07:02:27] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:
>   {"method":"GET","url":"http://192.168.1.64:8085/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"interception"}}
>   [] [2020-01-18 07:02:31] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:
>   {"method":"GET","url":"http://192.168.1.64:8085/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_SYSTEM_CONFIG"}}
>   []

How to debug above response?

Comment: it may be not nginx issue, i got this issue one module duplicated

Comment: Was this looping for you with all LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_SYSTEM_CONFIG? For me my local docker disk image size was nearly full and redis was failing causing this to loop